# How to list custom navigation menu with submenu?

Tags: routes

I have created a custom menu in a drop-down manner. How can I show this custom menu with it's subitems programatically, so that I could customise it's styling?

Comment: You can use superfish module. After that you just need to theme the menus.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below function to render your custom menu your way

```
function _custom_menu_overview_tree_form($tree) {
  $output = '';
  foreach ($tree as $data) {
    $item = $data['link'];
    if ($item && $item['hidden'] == 0) {
      if(strtolower($item['title']) == 'about us page condition'){
            $output .= '<li class="right-nav">';
      }else{
            $output .= '<li>';
      }
      (0 == $item['plid']) ? ($class = 'parent') : ($class = 'child');

      if(isset($item['options']['attributes'])) {
        $attributes = array('attributes' => array_merge($item['options']['attributes'], array('class' => array($class))));
      } else {
        $attributes = array('attributes' => array('class' => array($class)));
      }

      $output .= l($item['title'], $item['href'], $attributes);

      if ($data['below']) {
        $output .= '<ul class="sub-menu">' . _custom_menu_overview_tree_form($data['below']) . '</ul>';
      }
      $output .= '</li>';
    }
  }
  return $output;
}
```

And use below code in your html.tpl.php or where you want to render your menu

```
$menu_items = menu_tree_all_data('your menu name');
echo '<ul class="foot-nav">' . _custom_menu_overview_tree_form($menu_items) . '</ul>';
```

Please try this and let me know if any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I cracked through the following function

```
function load_menu_with_sub($menuname)
{
$links  = menu_tree_output(menu_tree_all_data($menuname));  
$menu_array = array();
$link_count =  count($links);
$i = 0;
foreach($links as $menu_item)
{
if($i < $link_count-2){   
$menu_array[$i] = array(
                      'menu_title' => $menu_item["#title"],
                      'menu_link' => $menu_item["#href"],                        
                     );
$count_sub = count($menu_item["#below"]);
$j = 0;

foreach($menu_item["#below"] as $sub_item)
{
if($j < $count_sub-2)
{
$menu_array[$i][$j] = array(
                      'menu_title' => $sub_item["#title"],
                      'menu_link' => $sub_item["#href"],                         
                     );
 $j = $j+1;
}
}
$i= $i+1;
}
}
}
```